# train Gensim word2vec using large txt file

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I have a large txt file(150MG) like this

```
'intrepid', 'bumbling', 'duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one', 'better', 'offering', 'considerable', 'cv', 'freshly', 'qualified', 'private', ...
```

I  wanna train word2vec model  model using that file but it gives me RAM problem.i dont know how to feed txt file to word2vec model.this is my code.i know that my code has problem but i don't know where is it.

```
import gensim 


f = open('your_file1.txt')
for line in f:
    b=line
   model = gensim.models.Word2Vec([b],min_count=1,size=32)

w1 = "bad"
model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1)
```

Comment: you are creating one model per line of the input file (f). This is not how you train a model. Read all the sentences and then train a model.

Comment: it gives my Ram error.

Comment: whole file is a sentence.

Comment: yes, thats because you are creating too many model objects (one per line). As I mentioned in the above comment, the way you are training the model is wrong

Comment: above code wont give error.it dosn't work at all.when i tried to give the whole file it gives me error.

Comment: how to give it  whole file ?  it is large and give me error.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an iterator that reads your file one line at a time instead of reading everything in memory at once. The following should work:

```
class SentenceIterator: 
    def __init__(self, filepath): 
        self.filepath = filepath 

    def __iter__(self): 
        for line in open(self.filepath): 
            yield line.split() 

sentences = SentenceIterator('datadir/textfile.txt') 
model = Word2Vec(sentences)
```

Comment: I added this (
w1 = "good"
model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1))at the end of your code but it gives me "word 'good' not in vocabulary"

Comment: That must be a problem with your input data. Make sure that your data file is a text file with one sentence per line (written normally with spaces between words, not as a list of words).

Comment: is it ok if each sentence starts  with open   bracket and close with close bracket?

Comment: Not with the code I wrote but you can of course change the code to fit your data. In the end you want `sentences` (i.e. the model input) to be an iterator of lists of words. In my code this is done by `line.split()` which splits each line of your file on spaces.

Comment: Can you instead just paste the first 5 lines or so in your question so I can see what the file looks like?