# Read 20gigabyte text as a list for the gensim Word2vec analysis

Tags: python, list, gensim, word2vec

I have the approximately 20gigabyte text data which is separated by \n.

I want to read that text as list to put it in the gensim library's Word2vec analysis(As far as I know, only the list form of input is allowed for the gensim Word2vec process).

I tried to read the text data line by line and append to the empty list. But it keep caused Memory error.

Since according to what I found in searching, read line by line does not really damage to the memory usage, I suspect it could be because of the process of appending results to the list. But I don't know how can I solve this problem.

My computer's RAM size is 32gb. and I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS and python 3 with pycharm.

Is it fundamentally impossible to load the 20gb of text file as a list in my computer..? which means that I better to add more RAM size to the computer.

Also, I wonder If it would be better to read as a csv not as a text because I found that pandas have good tools to read huge file. (I tried with this approach but I failed to convert the text column to the list because of the memory issue)

This is the code I used. Thanks for any advice.

```
##tried with text file
corpus = []
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        corpus.append(line.splitlines()[0])


##tried with dataframe
iter_csv = pd.read_csv("textfile.csv", iterator=True, sep=',', chunksize=300, header=None
                       , usecols=[4], names=['text'],encoding='UTF-8')
df_forCount_tmp = pd.concat(iter_csv, axis=0, ignore_index=True) 
#memory error....
corpus = []
def convertTolist(text):
    return ast.literal_eval(text)

for dfi, df in df_forCount_tmp.iterrows():
    corpus.extend(convertTolist(df['text']))
```

Comment: Can you deliver input to Word2vec one line at at a time?

Comment: oh I never thought that way. I don't know that is possible or not. I will search about that. Thanks. If that is possible, maybe I don't have to read all of data at once.

Comment: If inputting one at a time is possible you can use a generator and that will alleviate the memory problem. (If you don't know what those are they are quite easy to google)

Comment: Did you try `f.readlines()`? It is the most efficient mechanism. If it does not work, nothing else works, and your only option is to feed data to gensym in chunks.

Comment: I tried realines and it caused the memory error. so I tried with read line by line using readline. But it still cause error when I append it to the list... maybe you are right. I better to find the way to how to chunk.

Comment: Bill, I found this post 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086734/train-gensim-word2vec-using-large-txt-file' is this what you were trying to explain? I will keep search about that. Thanks a lot.